# How do i Clear form data after submitting it (Java app)?

Tags: java, netbeans

java app using Apache Netbeans and what i want is for the all text fields to clear up after submitting the data into the database

here is the code

```java
    private void reservenowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       String rname = name.getText();
       int mcontact = Integer.parseInt(contact.getText());
       String emailad = email.getText();

       SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       String rdate = dateformat.format(date.getDate());
       String rpurpose = purpose.getText();

        PreparedStatement st;
        String query = "insert into transactions(name, contact, email, date, purpose) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            st = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

            st.setString(1, rname);
            st.setInt(2, mcontact);
            st.setString(3, emailad);
            st.setString(4, rdate);
            st.setString(5, rpurpose);

            if(st.executeUpdate() > 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reservation Success");

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

how do i clear it after the messageDialog pops up

Comment: It seems you want to clear name, contact and email. To answer your question we need to know what type (class) they are. The code you showed above is totally not related to the core of your question.

Comment: Set the input fields with blank text e.g. `name.setText("");`

Comment: where should i put it

Comment: After `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reservation Success");`